# Find the distribution of $\beta$ error in ordinary least squares

Tags: regression, self-study, least-squares, matrix, estimators

Let $\hat\beta$ be the least squares estimator of $\beta$ in the regression model $y = x \beta + \mu$ where x is an $n \times k$ matrix with rank k and $\mu \tilde ~ N(0, \sigma^2 I)$.

1) Find the non-random matrices $A$ and $B$, such that $\hat\beta$ - $\beta$ can be written in the form $A\mu$ and the sum of the squared residuals can be written as $\mu'B\mu$.

2) Show that $B$ is idempotent and that $AB=0$

3) Indicate how these results enable one to obtain the distribution of

\begin{align}
 \frac{ (\hat\beta - \beta)'X'X(\hat\beta - \beta) }{(Y-X\hat\beta)'(Y-X\hat\beta)}.
 \frac{ n-k }{k}.
\end{align}

I think I can handle the second part (2), but I have a problem getting the non-random matrices and part 3

Comment: Please explain what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag as well.

Comment: Hints: it is not true that $A$ is square as $\mu$ is $n\times 1$ and $\beta$ is $k\times 1$, so $A$ must be $k\times n$. Take the expression for the OLS estimator and substitute for $y$.

Answer (score 1):

(Since this is tagged as self-study, just some tips without details.)

1. Note that the solution of OLS is

   $\hat{\beta} = \frac{X^Ty}{X^TX}$. (1)

   In addtion, it's given that

   $y = X \beta + \mu$. (2)

   Now insert (2) into (1), subtract $\beta$, and show that all terms cancel out, except those multiplying $\mu$. This should give you the $A$ solving $\hat{\beta} - \beta = A\mu$.

   For $B$, see [the part in the Wikipedia entry discussing estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Estimation), in particular the *annihilator* matrix $M$.
2. Once you solve $A$ and $B$, this should be easy. As a hint, note that in the same Wikipedia entry, the *projection* matrix $P$ satisfies $P^2 = P$.
3. In 
   $\frac{ (\hat\beta - \beta)^TX^TX(\hat\beta - \beta) }{(Y-X\hat\beta)^T(Y-X\hat\beta)}$,

   substitute the expression you found for $\hat\beta - \beta$, and consider how the denominator relates to the residual sum of squares. After some substitutions, use known properties of the normal distribution.

Comment: According to the guidelines, I have calculated matrices $A$ and $B$. Check in the comment if they are correct.

Comment: @Alexxio No, both are wrong. For the first, note that $\hat{\beta} - \beta = \frac{X^T(X\beta + \mu)}{X^TX} - \beta $, and continue from here. For the second, try to see why it is the square of the annihilator matrix.

Comment: @Alexxio $\hat\beta - \beta = \frac{X^T(X\beta + \mu)}{X^TX} - \beta =  \frac{X^TX\beta + X^T\mu -  X^tX \beta}{X^TX} = \frac{X^T \mu}{X^T X}$. For the annihilator matrix, read the Wikipedia entry.

Comment: ok so in this case, A = $\frac{x^T}{x^Tx}$ , right?

Comment: That is correct. Please now read the wiki in the link, and see why $B$ is the square of the annihilator matrix.

Comment: @Alexxio No, that's not how matrix algebra works. I think you need to first review a more basic course than this one.

Comment: Sure but I have a test in approx 48 hours which covers this, so I better get a work around it as fast as I can

Comment: @Alexxio Well, note that you cannot cancel matrices appearing in the nominator and denominator. Good luck on your test.

Comment: Thanks, One more thing, on the wiki page we have, Residual sum of squares (RSS) = $(y-xb)^T(y-xb)$ , should we replace $y$ and equate that to $\mu'B\mu$ to get matrix B?

Comment: @Alexxio I don't see how you can do that directly. Note that it's proven there that the annihilator matrix $M$ satisfies $y - \hat{y} = M \mu$, so the RSS is $\mu^2 M^2 \mu$. Once again, good luck on your exam.

Answer (score 0):

1) The solution of OLS is

$\hat{\beta} = \frac{X^Ty}{X^TX}$. (1)

We have:

$y = X \beta + \mu$. (2)

Therefore,
  $\hat{\beta} = \frac{\beta + \mu}{X^TX}$.
               = $\frac{\beta + \mu}{X^TX}$

=                 $\beta - \hat\beta = x^{-1}\mu$

hence A = $x^{-1}$

2) $\beta = (y - x)^T(y - xb)$

= $(x\beta + \mu - xb)^T(x\beta + \mu - xb)$

=$\mu'\mu = \mu'B\mu$

=$B=1$   (Am not sure about this)